# What is the !default keyword in bootstrap and foundation scss frameworks used for?

Tags: css, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

Example:

```
$link-color: $mycolor !default;
```

I have a theory, but I want to validate it here.
I know that *initial* is used to set an attribute back to the browsers default.  Using !default overrides the browser's native default value and replaces $link-color with the value of $mycolor from the example above.

Am I understanding that correctly?

Attempts at googling this question has lead me to many blog posts about the bootstrap and foundation frameworks, but I have not found a straightforward answer to what *!default* specifically does. I'm guessing because google ignores the bang (!) so it looks like I'm asking about some other kind of default value.

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`!default` is part of Sass' variables handling. The generated CSS which reaches the browser will never contain "!default".

Quoting the [docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_defaults_):

> ### Variable Defaults: `!default`
>
> You can assign to variables if they aren’t already assigned by adding
>   the `!default` flag to the end of the value. This means that if the
>   variable has already been assigned to, it won’t be re-assigned, but if
>   it doesn’t have a value yet, it will be given one.

---

`$link-color` is merely a variable. In framework context, `!default` is used to not overwrite customizations made by you or other included modules, while providing a default value for the variable if it hasn't been given a value yet.

Comment: **JS** equivalent: `foo = foo || bar;`. **Java** equivalent `if(foo == null) {foo = bar;}`. **C#** equivalent: `foo = foo ?? bar;`.

Comment: Javascript ES11 introduced nullish coalescing operator `??` now as well